# Element-wise multiply of two numpy array of different shapes

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two numpy arrays `F` and `C` of dimensions `NxM` and `MxB`. How can I get a matrix with elements `Result[n,m,b] = F[n,m]*C[m,b]` with dimensions `NxMxB` in an efficient manner?

Comment: Multiplying matrices of size NxM and MxB will produce a matrix of size NxB. How would you define the multiplication such that the result is NxMxB?

Comment: You can reshape it to allow broadcasting with `F[:, :, np.newaxis] * C[np.newaxis, :, :]`. Not sure if that's the result you're interested in. Can you give an example of expected input and output?

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right. I didn't fully understand the numpy rules of broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the solution by @Nick Odell comments works and is fast, it is perhaps not very readable. Another option is to use [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which allows you to explicitely state which dimensions have to be multiplied and which ones must be summed. In your case, you could do

```py
import numpy as np

N = 20
M = 40
B = 10

F = np.random.rand(N,M)
C = np.random.rand(M,B)

Result = np.einsum('nm,mb->nmb', F, C) 

print(Result.shape) # (20,40,10)
```

Here `'nm,mb->nmb'` means:

- `nm`: first matrix has dimensions with subscripts `n` and `m` respectively,
- `mb`: second matrix has dimenisons with subscripts `m` and `b` respectively,
- `-->nmb`: multiply `n` x `m` x `b`, do not sum over any subscript.